# Capture the text from screen for rivo/tview console application

Tags: go

I have console app that uses github.com/rivo/tview. I need to capture text from it (to use in documentation). tcell.Screen interface that tview application uses to display characters on screen has GetContent(x, y int) function, but it is not suitable for me as then screen captures will depend on what size of terminal window it will be during application operation. I would like to have standard 80x24 characters.

I have created my own Screen implementation:

```
type CaptureScreen struct {
    width  int
    height int
    data   [][]rune
}
```

So it would have Capture() function:

```
func (s *CaptureScreen) Capture(filePath string) error {
    f, err := os.Create(filePath)
...
}
```

Added my custom Size function:

```
func (s *CaptureScreen) Size() (width, height int) {
    return s.width, s.height
}
```

And SetContent

```
func (s *CaptureScreen) SetContent(x int, y int, mainc rune, combc []rune, style tcell.Style) {
    s.data[y][x] = mainc
}
```

I have implemented all other Screen interface functions as doing nothing:

```
func (s *CaptureScreen) Init() error { return nil }
func (s *CaptureScreen) Resume() error { return nil }
func (s *CaptureScreen) Beep() error { return nil }
...
```

Then I have set my application screen to be CaptureScreen

```
app := tview.NewApplication()
screen = NewCaptureScreen(80, 24)
app.SetScreen(screen)
```

and then used Capture function while creating pages (I use tview.Pages):

```
grid := tview.NewGrid()
grid.Add...
...
pages.AddPage("page name", grid, true, true)
pages.Draw(screen)
screen.Capture("capture.txt")
```

Result is disappointing: All captures have size 15 by 10 characters! (these are default dimensions of tview.Box).

I have added logging to CaptureScreen and it appears that Size() function is never called!

I am puzzled. How to create 80x24 screen captures?